# How to make same button do different actions depending on dropdown menu result with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, drop-down-menu

is there a way to make the same button do different actions depending on what the user chooses from drop down menu?

I tried this for example, but it doesn't work:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

def say_hello():
    hello_label = Label(root, text= "Hello")
    hello_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

def say_goodbye():
    bye_label = Label(root, text= "Goodbye")
    bye_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

do = ""
drop_table = ttk.Combobox(root, values=["Choose Action..", "Say Hello","Say Goodbye"])
drop_table.current(0)
drop_table.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

selected = drop_table.get()

if selected == "Say Hello":
    do = say_hello
if selected == "Say Goodbye":
    do = say_goodbye

button = Button(root, text= "Choose", command = do)
button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add conditions inside `do`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to link your button to a function and include your if statements in the function. Then use your function as the command for your button like this.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

def say_hello():
    hello_label = Label(root, text= "Hello")
    hello_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

def say_goodbye():
    bye_label = Label(root, text= "Goodbye")
    bye_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

do = ""
drop_table = ttk.Combobox(root, values=["Choose Action..", "Say Hello","Say Goodbye"])
drop_table.current(0)
drop_table.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


def action():
    selected = drop_table.get()
    if selected == "Say Hello":
        say_hello()
    if selected == "Say Goodbye":
        say_goodbye()
        

button = Button(root, text= "Choose", command= action)
button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```